# How to bookmark favorite addons from opera addons?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, opera

How to bookmark favorite addons from opera addons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to bookmark favorite addons from opera addons?

There's no such feature in Opera. I suggest you request that feature at https://forums.opera.com/category/15/suggestions-and-feature-requests